# What do I have to do to get EWL Shortcut URLs to work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, friendly-url, enterprise-web-library

I have this code:

```
protected override IEnumerable<ShortcutUrlResolver> GetShortcutUrlResolvers() {
    return new[]
        {
            new ShortcutUrlResolver( "someShortcut", ConnectionSecurity.SecureIfPossible, () => SmartRedirector.GetInfo( Pages.One.Two.GetInfo().GetUrl() ) ),
            new ShortcutUrlResolver( "", ConnectionSecurity.SecureIfPossible, () => Pages.Portals.GetInfo() )
        };
}
```

If I go to `mysite/`, I end up at the Portals page *(the second shortcut above)*. If I go to mysite/someShortcut, I get a error:

```
this page is no longer available .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I wasn't trying to navigate to "mysite/someShortcut", I was trying to navigate to "mysite/someShortcut/", with a trailing slash. The slash counts. So, removing the slash from my URL makes it work. Also, I can include both "someShortcut/" and "someShortcut" as shortcut URLs and then either one will work.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the shortcut URLs defined properly, and I don't believe you can get the "The page you requested is no longer available" error when accessing a shortcut URL, so it looks like the problem is coming from a redirect you're doing on your own after the shortcut URL is followed.

Comment: If I redirect to the exact same destination (SmartRedirector.GetInfo( Pages.One.Two.GetInfo().GetUrl() )) from anywhere else in the system (from a link, for example), it works fine.